# GCM - What is the special message from GCM look like when the limit of 100 messages is reached?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, message

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#send-msg
I saw this note : 
Note: There is a limit of 100 messages that can be stored without collapsing. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. When the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync from the app server.

I have no idea what is the special message from GCM look like and how can I handle it ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just try and see?

Comment: I tried to turn off wifi and send over 100 GCM messages , but I still received full messages that I had sent when I turn wifi on and I didn't receive any special  message from Google.
P/S: I used Xamarin.Android to develop this app.

Answer (score 2):

implement

```
@Override public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
    Log.w("mcheck", "onDeletedMessages");
    Log.e("mcheck", "messages deleted");
  }
```

from GcmListenerService.
That method will fier every time, gcm delete cached messages for any reason including  exceed of 100 messages limit